# How to identify CAAnimation in delegate and release controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation, core-graphics

I *have* seen [How to identify CAAnimation within the animationDidStop delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255086/how-to-identify-caanimation-within-the-animationdidstop-delegate), this is an addition to it.

I'm unable to get this working properly. I have an animation, and I'd like to release the controller that it was run in after the end of the animation.
Example: The controller translates from right -> left then releases itself.

Defining the animation:

```
NSValue *end = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(800, self.view.center.y)];
NSValue *start = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:self.view.center];

CABasicAnimation *moveAnimation;        
moveAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
moveAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
moveAnimation.duration = 0.45f;

moveAnimation.fromValue = start;
moveAnimation.toValue = end;

// actually set the position
[self.view.layer setPosition:[end CGPointValue]];

moveAnimation.delegate = self;
moveAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[self.view.layer addAnimation:moveAnimation forKey:MOVING_OUT];
```

Inside the delegate method:

```
- (void) animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag 
{
    CAAnimation *check = [self.view.layer animationForKey:MOVING_OUT];

    if (theAnimation == check)
    {
        //[check release];
        [self release];

    }
}
```

If I leave this code as-is, my controller doesn't get dealloc'd (due to the retain call by the animation).
If I run `[check release]`, I get the `message sent to deallocated instance`.

Does anyone know what's wrong? 
Is there another way to identify a CAAnimation in the `animationDidStop` delegate WITHOUT specifying `removedOnCompletion = NO`?

EDIT: 
Forgot to mention. By not specifying that `removedOnCompletion = NO`, `animationForKey:` will return NULL. Hence I'm unable to identify the animation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what your problem is here, but it may help you to know that `CAAnimation` instances are generic KVO containers, so you can add custom info to them:

```
[myAnimation setValue: @"check" forKey: @"name"];
```

You can then check against that:

```
if ([[theAnimation valueForKey: @"name"] isEqual: @"check"])
    // ...
```

Does that help?

Comment: Combine the KVO stuff with `removedOnCompletion` :)

Comment: removedOnCompletion = YES is exactly what was needed for me! Thanks! But to point out to others, I checked the documentation and removedOnCompletion defaults to YES, I had unwittingly set it to NO in some testing thinking it did something else.

Answer (score 4):

I think the eventual reason is CAAnimation.delegate is a retain property (very strange oops!).

The header file definition is:

```
/* The delegate of the animation. This object is retained for the
 * lifetime of the animation object. Defaults to nil. See below for the
 * supported delegate methods. */

@property(retain) id delegate;
```

To let self get release, the animation must be removed from layer, like:

```
[self.view.layer removeAnimationForKey:@THE_ANIMATION_KEY];
```