# UIView layer's animationForKey: is always nil

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, core-animation

I have a rather curious problem.

I have a view that I'm animating with a `CAKeyframeAnimation`. The animation works as expected however, once the delegate's `animationDidStop:finished` method is fired, the layer associated with the view always returns `nil` when checked with the layer's `animationForKey:` method.

Here's an illustration of the problem:

```
// This is in the view controller
- (void) doAnimation:(id)sender {
    CAKeyframeAnimation *positionAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];

    [positionAnimation setValues:arrayOfPoint];
    [positionAnimation setDuration:0.5];
    // ViewController is the delegate and has the animationDidStop:finished: method
    positionAnimation.delegate = self;
    [positionAnimation setValue:@"I am Text" forKeyPath:@"positionAnimation"];

    [someView.layer addAnimation:positionAnimation forKey:@"positionAnimation"];
    someView.layer.position = newPosition;
}
```

Elsewhere in the controller, I have the `animationDidStop:finished:` method defined as follows:

```
- (void) animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag {

        NSArray *array = [someView.layer animationKeys];
        NSString *stringValue = [anim valueForKey:@"positionAnimation"];

        NSLog(@"valueForKey: %@", stringValue);
        // Prints 'I am Text'

        if(anim == [someView.layer animationForKey:@"positionAnimation"]) {
            //THIS NEVER GET CALLED
        }
}
```

Why does the if block never evaluate to True? Why is `[someView.layer animationForKey:@"positionAnimation"]` always `nil`? Additionally, `stringValue` has the correct data, but array is also `nil`.

Comment: I saw this [explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255086/how-to-identify-caanimation-within-the-animationdidstop-delegate/5010291#5010291); can anyone else confirm this theory- please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can just guess, but maybe when method `animationDidStop:finished:` is called your animation has already been removed from the layer. So `[someView.layer animationForKey:@"positionAnimation"]` is nil.

Hope this'll help

Comment: Thanks - It did. More specifically, I had to call the method `[positionAnimation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];` before adding the animation to the layer. 

So indeed it seems as if the following are happening: 1: When the animation is added to the layer it is done so via a copy. 2: The animation is removed from the layer once the animation is done.  (IMHO) It's better to set a KVO on animation object directly, then check for that KV in the `animationDidStop:finished:` method.