# CAAnimation determining which animation is which

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, caanimation

I have three CAShapeLayer each with a different path to it, but the three of the layer is applied the same animation, which is:

```
 [self animateToLineLayer:self.leftDottedLine_ withKey:@"leftLineAnimated"];

   - (void) animateToLineLayer:(CAShapeLayer *) line withKey:(NSString *) key
    {
        CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
        [pathAnimation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]];
        [pathAnimation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f]];
        [pathAnimation setDuration:10.0];
        [pathAnimation setDelegate:self];
        [pathAnimation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
        [line addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:key];
    }

    then I try to find this animation back by doing:

    - (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)animation finished:(BOOL)flag
    {
        if (animation == [self.leftDottedLine_ animationForKey:@"strokeEnd"]) {
            NSLog(@"DONE");
        }

        if (![self.leftDottedLine_ isNotNull]){
            NSLog(@"NIL");
        }

        NSLog(@"JUST DONE");
    }
```

but the issue is that it never prints DONE! Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look here for tips on how to identify animations in the animationDidStop delegate:
[How to identify CAAnimation within the animationDidStop delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255086/how-to-identify-caanimation-within-the-animationdidstop-delegate)

Are you sure you set self as the delegate? Also, maybe == doesn't work. Try isEqualTo: or a string comparison as stated in the above link.