# in animationDidStop, animation 's address is not the same address as the animation i add to the layer?

Tags: iphone, ios

code like this: i stored 3 animations in my viewcontroller , but when - (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag is called ,i found the anim 's address is not the same as any of them,why?

```
- (void) redoAni
{
    circleHalfCaloryMask.alpha = 1;
    circleHalfTimeMask.alpha = 1;
    circleHalfStopWatchMask.alpha = 1;


    //[circleHalfCalory removeFromSuperview];
    //circleHalfCalory.alpha = 0;
    [circleHalfCaloryMask.layer addAnimation:rotate3 forKey:@"rotate3"];
    [circleHalfStopWatchMask.layer addAnimation:rotate2 forKey:@"rotate2"];
    [circleHalfTimeMask.layer addAnimation:rotate1 forKey:@"rotate1"];
}



    - (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag
    {
        if (anim == rotate1)
        {
            circleHalfTimeMask.alpha = 0;
        }
        else if (anim == rotate2)
        {
            circleHalfStopWatchMask.alpha = 0;
        }
        else if (anim == rotate3)
        {
            circleHalfCaloryMask.alpha = 0;
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
```

in gdb:

```
rotate1 CABasicAnimation *  0x07297280
rotate2 CABasicAnimation *  0x072899a0
rotate3 CABasicAnimation *  0x07297d40
anim    CABasicAnimation *  0x07285010
```

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255086/how-to-identify-caanimation-within-the-animationdidstop-delegate?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Documentation says:

> - (void)addAnimation:(CAAnimation *)anim forKey:(NSString *)key
>
> anim
>
> The animation to be added to the render tree. Note that the object is
> copied by the render tree, not referenced. Any subsequent
> modifications to the object will not be propagated into the render
> tree.

Comment: OK,i got it ,thanks alot,so if i want to distinguish them ,i must set some attribute .like :[rotate2 setValue:@"rotate2" forKey:@"id"];