# Tell subroutine that a CAAnimation has finished

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an instance method that will perform animation of a UIView on its shadowOpacity property forever(never stop).

So I just put the animation codes into a while loop. But the problem is that, the subroutine loop can not start until previous animation has finished.

Here I just make a simple `sleep(0.5)` system call. It certainly left some display problems.

My question is how to implement an NO-TIME-GAP repeat animation here?

```
- (void)animateShadowRepeatly  
{
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"shadowOpacity"];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        while (YES) {
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                animation.duration = 0.5;
                if (_actionTarget2.layer.shadowOpacity <= 0.1) {
                    animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
                    animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
                    _actionTarget2.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
                } else {
                    animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
                    animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
                    _actionTarget2.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0;
                }
                [_actionTarget2.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"shadowOpacity"];
            });
            sleep(0.5);//here I must pasuse the while loop until animation on actionTarget2 finished.I think sleep(0.5) here is not a good implement,How to make an elegant implement for the dependency on animation purpose?
         }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. The sleep will prevent the animation from starting, since it blocks the main thread. And you can't run animations on a background thread.

What you want to do is set yourself up as the delegate of the animation and add a completion method. Then in the completion method you trigger the next animation.

I wrote a post here on SO That explains how to add a completion block to your animation and trigger THAT when the animation finishes. Check out [**this link.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255086/how-to-identify-caanimation-within-the-animationdidstop-delegate/8748474#8748474)

Comment: thanks for your help.  I create a delegate method for receiving this event and inside it I make a call [self animateShadowRepeatly]. It works as my expectation.