# Rotation animation of multiple UIButtons, how can animationDidStop know which stopped?

Tags: ios, animation, swift, uiview, uibutton

I'm trying to make four UIButtons rotate in Swift. I got this:

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {

func rotate360Degrees(duration: CFTimeInterval = 1.0, completionDelegate: AnyObject? = nil) {
    let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
    rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0)
    rotateAnimation.duration = duration

    if let delegate: AnyObject = completionDelegate {
        rotateAnimation.delegate = delegate
    }
    self.layer.addAnimation(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
}
}
```

But I need it to repeat. In my UIViewController I used the animationDidStop function but how can I know which of the four animation triggers it? It has a parameter called CAAnimation but I cannot compare it to anything. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Re-write your method using CATransition and use the solution from this question: 
[How to identify CAAnimation within the animationDidStop delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255086/how-to-identify-caanimation-within-the-animationdidstop-delegate)